# Extension method calling other extension wethod

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have been trying to write an extension methods for generating string with datetime in the right timezone and format. My code is:

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static string ToZoneString(this DateTime date, string zoneId, string formatter)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, zone).ToString(formatter);
    }

    public static string ToZoneString(this DateTimeOffset date, string zoneId, string formatter)
    {   
        //in this case all goes well
        //TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
        //return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, zone).ToString(formatter); 

        //in this case an unexpected error occurs        
        return date.ToZoneString(zoneId, formatter);
    }
}
```

But after compiling and running my ASP.NET MVC project

> "An unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework exception occured in w3wp.exe"

has occured. Why is it so? If I don't call  first method in the second one and just do the same all executes correctly.

Comment: wouldn't it be `StackOverflowException`? i think you call *2nd* method from *2nd* method; even if code looks the same, different overloads of `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` are used

Comment: If it gets to second method, will be recursion without ending

Comment: You ask a question on stackoverflow because your program gets stackoverflow :)

Comment: What is your intention, please, with this call?

Comment: Thanks all for a help. I'm foolish. After casting to DatTime or calling date.DateTime.ToZoneString(zoneId, formatter) all works as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if you update second method this way it will work for you:

```
public static string ToZoneString(this DateTimeOffset date, string zoneId, string formatter)
{   
    //in this case all goes well
    //TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
    //return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, zone).ToString(formatter); 

    //in this case an unexpected error occurs        
    return date.DateTime.ToZoneString(zoneId, formatter);
}
```

But depending on your need, you might choose different method to get DateTime from DateTimeOffset(`LocalDateTime`, `UtcDateTime`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. return date.DateTime.ToZoneString(zoneId, formatter); also is possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method doesn't call your first one, it just calls your second one again. Which calls your second one again. Which calls your second one again. And so on, until your whole process crashes with a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling the first method. Your second method calls *itself*. You need to convert `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime` first if you want to call your first method.